# Scala - Mapping one key to multiple values of different type

Tags: scala

So I am trying to play around with data in Scala. I've hit a roadblock now. I'm reading a text file into the program that contains a list, made a case class to read each header. I've managed to do a mapping of (String, String) to a double, but I would like this instead to be mapping a string to a (string, double). The relevant code is here:

```
def averageofactions (): Map[(String,String),  Double] = {

  datafile.groupBy(d => (d.user, d.typeofaction))
.mapValues(averageof => averageof.map(_.amount).sum /averageof.length)
 }
```

Which gives me what I want (the average amount of a particular action by a particular user) but formatted so that it gives (UserID, Action) -> Average, whereas I simply want a list like

UserID1:

Action1 -> Average

Action2 -> Average

and so on. I understand that probably the best way to do this is by changing it such that I return Map[String, (String,Double)], or perhaps a multimap/hashmap, but I'm unsure how to go about this. I tried:

```
def modifiedaverage (): Map[String, (List[String], Double)] = {

  datafile.groupBy(d => (d.user))
.mapValues(averageof => (averageof.map(_.typeofaction),     averageof.map(_.amount).sum/averageof.length))

}
```

but the output here is totally strange. How can I rewrite this function to give me what I want?

Comment: Looks like you want it to return a `Map[String, Map[String, Double]]`, and not a `Map[String, (List[String], Double)]` because each "action" has its own "value" - right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the output to be of type `Map[String, Map[String, Double]]` (map of maps), you can group by `actionoftype` on each result of grouping by `user`:

```
def averageofactions(): Map[String, Map[String, Double]] = {
  datafile.groupBy(_.user)
    .mapValues(_.groupBy(_.typeofaction)
      .mapValues(averageof => averageof.map(_.amount).sum /averageof.length))
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to "flatten" this into a *sequence* (and not a map) of `(String, String, Double)` tuples, you can:

```
def averageofactions(): Seq[(String, String, Double)] = {
  datafile.groupBy(averageof => (averageof.user, averageof.typeofaction))
    .mapValues(averageof => averageof.map(_.amount).sum /averageof.length)
    .map { case ((user, action), avg) => (user, action, avg) }.toSeq
}
```

Comment: Ah I see! This makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!